# How to check if the content of an element with a width of 100% is overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my structure:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="container">
        <slot />
    </div>
</div>
```

The `Card` has a fixed `width` of `33rem`.
The `container` is `width` `100%`.
I need to know when does the slotted element overflows so that I can add a class to the `container` element with `word-break` applied to it.

I tried this:

```
 if(el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('overflows')
}
```

but it doesn't work because the `el(='container')` is `width 100%`.
How do I do it then?

PS:
My `container` has these styles applied to it:

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that can reproduce the problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And what is the content of the `<slot />` element? Isn't text content automatically wraps when content is exceeding its parent element? Unless the text content is overflowed and there's no white space between it

Comment: @Joshua The content of `<slot />` is just a text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your example works if you look at the snippet where I just wrote your code. If you have the `white-space: nowrap;`, the log appears, if you remove it, it does not anymore.
If it is not exactly the example you meant, please give a working snippet to understand your problem better.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('cont');

if (el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight) {
    console.log('overflows')
}
```

```css
#cont {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div id="cont" class="container">
        Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use or ask for external code sites when a stack snippet will just do.

Comment: I added the `white-space: nowrap;` to the element, but it still does not work, but any how, the element cannot have `nowrap` on it, because it needs to be on two lines too.

Answer (score 0):

I use this logic on document bodies successfully, but with containers Chromium does have bugs that could make some of these values return zero!

Perhaps it’s something to do with positioning, display and other properties.

```
if((e.scrollHeight>e.offsetHeight)||(e.scrollWidth>=e.offsetWidth)){
    
}
```

Btw, don't tell people what the container dimensions should be... PUT THEM IN THERE!

You should have a fully working example code with a Lorem ipsum included even.

Comment: What is `e` referring to?

Comment: My `el` is this: `const el = this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector('.card-headline')`

Comment: It's hard to show you a working snippet because these are Stencil Web Components, so it's not that easy to just replicate a part of a component in isolation.

Comment: I used your condition, but now it's always `true`.

Comment: I updated the question with the styles that I have applied to the `container`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding width: 0 to the flex-item element that had flex:1 on it.